# Доработка карусели jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, cleartimeout

Нашел на хабре простенькую карусель, css переделал под себя, а вот доработать jQuery script, знаний не хватает ))

- Мне нужно чтобы при наведении на карусель ее таймер останавливался, чтоб можно было спокойно рассмотреть картинки
- Хочу добавь под каруселью, такие маленькие кружочки, чтобы было понятно какие картинки сейчас активные, как в слайдерах

вот как сейчас выглядит карусель:  http://jsfiddle.net/aHL4v/

P.s. Mожно ли подключать 2 версии jQuery на одной страницы??
просто у меня есть табы(вкладки) которые работают только на версий 1.4.2, и слайдер на 1.7.1
не будут они ругаются друг на друга?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пауза прокрутки для карусели ([посмотреть](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/aHL4v/2/))**

**Было:**

```
$(function() {
    autoScrolling('.carousel:first');
});

function autoScrolling(carusel){
    setTimeout(function(){
        rightCarusel(carusel);
        autoScrolling(carusel);
    }, 3500);
};
```

**Стало:**

```
var pause = false; //Вводим глобальную переменную.

//Навели курсор на блок с картинками. Сигналим "стоп" карусели.
$('.carouselWrapper').hover(function(){pause = true;});
//Убрали курсор с блока с картинками. Сигналим "вперед" карусели.
$('.carouselWrapper').mouseout(function(){pause = false;});

$(function() {
    autoScrolling('.carousel:first');
});

function autoScrolling(carusel){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Проверяем глобальную переменную. Сигнала "Стоп" не было? Крутим карусель.
        if (!pause) {
            rightCarusel(carusel);            
        }
        autoScrolling(carusel);
    }, 3500);
};
```

---

**2 версии jQuery на одной странице**
Придется пройтись автозаменой по скриптам. Пример реализации:

```
<!-- Загружаем jQuery 1.4.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_4_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/your-tab-script.js"></script>
<!-- В файле your-tab-script.js (ваш скрипт с табами)
     заменить все символы $ на jQuery_1_4_2 -->

<!-- Загружаем jQuery 1.7.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/your-carusel-script.js"></script>
<!-- В файле your-carusel-script.js (ваш скрипт с каруселью)
     заменить все символы $ на jQuery_1_7_1 -->
```

---

Про кружочки не понял. Если четче опишите задачу, постараюсь помочь и обновлю ответ.

Comment: за помощь, брат, большое спасибо, реально выручил

на счет кружочков... вот что я имел ввиду:
http://s017.radikal.ru/i443/1401/84/e760216b01a0.jpg

Comment: по поводу jQuery, а что вам мешает использовать только последнюю? Скрипт под раннюю перестает работать? Его сложно исправить для работы на последнем?

Comment: да, верно.. табы перестают работать под последнюю

не знаю если сложно, я еще новичок в этом